# How to filter List View queryset based on the user status

Tags: django, django-views

Hey i have a listView that outputs list of events created. How can i filter based on the super user?

Basically i want the admin to see all the events: closed and open, but my users only see open one

```
class EventView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    template_name = "chat/events.html"
    model = Event
    context_object_name = 'events' 

    def get_queryset(self):
        kwargs = super(EventView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        print(kwargs)
        user_pk = self.kwargs['user_id']
        user = User.objects.get(pk=user_pk)
        print(user)
        if user.is_superuser:
            queryset = Event.objects.all()
            return queryset
        else:
            queryset = Event.objects.filter(is_open=True)
            return queryset
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are very close you just have to get the logged in user and prepare queryset accordingly:-

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset = Event.objects.all()
    else:
        queryset = Event.objects.filter(is_open=True)

    return queryset
```